# PHP form select list validation weird issue

Tags: php, forms

I am having a weird issue for validating a form select list (drop down) in PHP. In my HTML, when I use 0 (zero) as an `<option>` value and in PHP, checks if the incoming value is equal to 0 then don't submit the form, then the form doesn't get submitted even I choose some other `<option>` value e.g. "Delhi" rather than 0. Here's my HTML and PHP code to explain you more better:

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="">
    <table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="selcity">City:</label></th>
            <td><select name="selcity" id="selcity">
            <option value="0">Select Your City</option>
            <option value="Chandigarh" <?php if($city == "Chandigarh") echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Chandigarh</option>
            <option value="Delhi" <?php if($city == "Delhi") echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Delhi</option>
            <option value="Shimla" <?php if($city == "Shimla") echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Shimla</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Default form values
$city = NULL;

if(isset($_GET['btnsubmit']))
{
    $city = $_GET['selcity'];

    $errors = array();
    if($city == 0)
    {
        $errors[] = "Please select your city.";
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {
        // Do some mysql queries for saving data in table
        echo "You are registered.";
    }
    else
    {
        $error_list = "<div id='error'><strong>There are following errors with this form:</strong><ul>";
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            $error_list .= "<li>" . $error . "</li>";
        }
        $error_list .= "</ul></div>";
        echo $error_list;
    }
}
?>
```

However, when I change my HTML code to

```
<option value="">Select Your City</option>
```

and PHP code to

```
if($city == "")
{
    $errors[] = "Please select your city.";
}
```

then problem is solved. Why?

Comment: its the default behavior for using loose comparison, in PHP `$city == 0` is `true` will be the result in any of the choices you will select http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: oh then what should one use here?

Comment: use $city == "0" with double quotes as @Ghost described

Comment: ok i got it, thanks!